# Как открыть APK файл в Android Studio?

Tags: apk, android, android-studio

Как открыть APK файл в Android Studio?

Comment: Можно, но зачем это делать ВАМ и при чем тут IDE? Как вам "намекнул" @metalurgus, используйте архиватор, чтобы залезть внутрь..

Comment: На Github частенько бывают исходники приложений, не ленитесь там поискать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак. APK файл - это обычный ZIP архив, содержащий **скомпилированный** код. Android Studio не открывает APK файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Простой способ: использовать онлайн-инструмент http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk , загрузить apk и получить исходный код.

Процедура для декодирования .apk файлов, шаг за шагом:
Шаг 1:

```
Создайте новую папку и скопируйте файл .apk, который вы хотите декодировать.
Теперь переименуйте расширение этого .apk-файла в .zip (например, переименуйте с filename.apk в filename.zip) и сохраните его. Теперь вы можете получить доступ к файлам classes.dex и т. Д. На этом этапе вы можете видеть чертежи, но не файлы xml и java, поэтому продолжайте.
```

Шаг 2:

```
Теперь извлеките этот .zip-файл в ту же папку (или NEW FOLDER).
Загрузите dex2jar и извлеките его в ту же папку (или NEW FOLDER).
Переместите файл classes.dex в папку dex2jar.
Теперь откройте командную строку и смените каталог на эту папку (или NEW FOLDER). Затем напишите d2j-dex2jar classes.dex (для терминала mac или ubuntu write ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex) и нажмите enter. Теперь у вас есть файл classes.dex.dex2jar в той же папке.
Загрузите java decompiler , дважды щелкните по jd-gui, щелкните по открытому файлу и откройте classes.dex .dex2jar из этой папки: теперь вы получаете файлы классов.
Сохраните все эти файлы классов (в jd-gui, щелкните File -> Save All Sources) по имени src. На этом этапе вы получаете источник java, но файлы .xml по-прежнему не читаются, поэтому продолжайте.
```

Шаг 3:

Теперь откройте еще одну новую папку

```
Вставьте файл .apk, который вы хотите декодировать
Загрузите последнюю версию apktool И окно установки apktool (обе могут быть загружены из одной и той же ссылки ) и поместите их в ту же папку
Откройте командное окно
Теперь запустите команду, например apktool if framework-res.apk и следующую
apktool d myApp.apk (где myApp.apk обозначает имя файла, которое вы хотите декодировать)
```

теперь вы получаете папку с файлами в этой папке и можете легко прочитать XML-файлы apk.
Шаг 4:

Это не какой-либо шаг, просто скопируйте содержимое обеих папок (в данном случае и новую папку) в один файл

и наслаждайтесь источником код ...

Answer (score 0):

откройте меню Build | Analyze APK и затем выберите нужный файл.